# Automatic mute radio on power-off

Tags: audio, interference

I have a small FM radio module I bought off eBay that runs off a few AA batteries, and have it essentially plugged right into a pair of PC speakers I have on all the time. To save battery power, I turn the module off with a power switch built into the battery box. The problem with this setup is that when the power to the module is turned off, there's nothing controlling the signals on the headphone patch cord anymore, so it suddenly gets 60Hz line hum on it.

Is there a way to use a couple of transistors from the signal lines to ground, and bias them off while the power's on, so that when the power is turned off they ground the lines?

Or would it be easier to just add 10K resistors between the signal lines and ground, so it doesn't have as much opportunity to pick up line hum?

To be clear, adding a triple-pole, double-throw switch is NOT an approach I'm willing to take in this instance, as it's rather overkill for this situation, given that I already have a mute switch between the radio and the speakers. I'd rather this was automatic instead of manual, you see.

Comment: Transistors require power to switch them into conduction. What was your plan?

Comment: Show your plan schematically and, why not plug your headphones directly into the radio?

Comment: Have you tried adding the resistors? Does it work?

Comment: I forgot about the power issue, I'm not using headphones I'm using a pair of PC speakers with an integrated amp, and the resistors appear to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a pair of 1K resistors to pull the headphone jack's left and right channels to ground does not appear to affect the audio at all while it's running, and when off they do appear to get rid of most of the 60Hz line hum interference I'd ordinarily get when I turn the power to the radio off.